# @RequestMapping mapping does not work anymore in Spring 3.1

Tags: spring-mvc

I updated my project to use 3.1.0.RELEASE (actually - not me, but Spring Roo did it) from 3.0.6.RELEASE, and the following mapping does not work anymore:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/partners/public/logos/{id}/{filename}.{ext}")
public void partners_get_logo2(@PathVariable Long id,
        @PathVariable String filename, @PathVariable String ext,
        ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
...
}
```

How is it possible to map more than 2 path variables?

Comment: did you try escaping the dot \\, or just take the entire file name including the extension and split it inside your method

Comment: what exception you are getting..??

Comment: I have no exceptions, simply this method isn't invoked as ealier in Spring 3.0. This method is intended to generate images and thumbnails - maybe here is a trick?

Comment: I tried @PathVariable(value = "filename") String filename - but with the same effect.. seems new Spring 3.1 does not distinguish path variables by name... (((

Comment: When you start Spring, in the logs you can see all the request mappings being processed. You can look there to see if the mapping is actually taken in account or if there is an error mapping it.